# Infinite Slideshow

Tags: jquery, slideshow, infinite-loop

I need some help about infinite slideshow concept.
What I need is similar to this image:

[image]

Well, I have this structure in HTML and CSS and I use imagens on background of divs, but I don't know how do the infinite effect with jquery. Anybody have patience to explain?

I found some codes, but they don't work like exacly I expected, with a centralized div and a cut of the prev and next slide.

I say thank you to anyone helping me from now.

Comment: Hi.. You can achieve this by using owl carousel

Answer (score 1):

Use this plugin and make your desired carousel
https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/merge.html

Answer (score 0):

Check this demo

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    items:5,
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    merge:true,
    responsive:{
        678:{
            mergeFit:true
        },
        1000:{
            mergeFit:false
        }
    }
});
```

```css
.item {
 height: 10rem;
 background-color: #4DC7A0;
 padding: 1rem;
 color: #fff;
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.green.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="item" data-merge="1"><h2>1</h2></div>
    <div class="item" data-merge="2"><h2>2</h2></div>
    <div class="item" data-merge="1"><h2>3</h2></div>
    <div class="item" data-merge="3"><h2>4</h2></div>
    <div class="item" data-merge="6"><h2>6</h2></div>
    <div class="item" data-merge="2"><h2>7</h2></div>
    <div class="item" data-merge="1"><h2>8</h2></div>
    <div class="item" data-merge="3"><h2>9</h2></div>
    <div class="item"><h2>10</h2></div>
    <div class="item"><h2>11</h2></div>
    <div class="item" data-merge="2"><h2>12</h2></div>
    <div class="item"><h2>13</h2></div>
    <div class="item"><h2>14</h2></div>
    <div class="item"><h2>15</h2></div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, i see that example, but I need all DIVs with the same width, like a image in my question. In the viewport, first slide centralized and 25% of next and lastest slides on the sides, do you understand?

This plugin don't do exacly I need.

Comment: remove data-merge attribute form items and bro please check the whole doc of owl carousel you will find everything what you want. Seems that you want that some one code this as per your requirement